# Equilibrium point of a linear second order equation with constants

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is as follows:

> The general form of a linear, homogeneous, second order equation with constant coefficients is $d^2y/dt^2 + p(dy/dt) + qy = 0$
>
> (a) Show that if $q$ does not equal $0$, then the origin is the only equilibrium point of the system.
>
> (b) Show that if $q$ does not equal $0$, then the only solution of the second-order equation with $y$ constant is $y(t)=0$ for all $t$.

I solved part a by creating a system of equations:

$dy/dt = v$

$dv/dt = -pv -qy$

I then set each equation equal to zero. Since $v$ must equal zero, I plugged $v=0$ into the second equation: $-p(0) - qy = 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $-qy = 0$. Therefore, $y$ must equal zero to satisfy the equation since $q$ cannot be zero.

I'm not sure how to approach part $(b)$ because I don't understand how the two questions are any different.

Answer (score 0):

since $y$ is constant, we have: $$y'=0$$ and $$y''=0$$so that the equation becomes:
$$qy = 0$$
but $q \neq 0$, thus $y=0$